# Is there an expression to thank Hashem for good news?

Tags: words, hebrew

My friend just found out that her cancer is a treatable variety. Is there a Hebrew phrase to thank Hashem for this good news? Baruch Dayan HaEmet I believe is only for news of a death, but thanks for a merciful judgement?

Answer (score 3):

You should really ask a Rav.

In general, there's this Halakha (following quoted from [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bracha_for_good_or_bad_news)):

> For hearing good news from a reliable source which is good for oneself
>   and for others one should make the Bracha of HaTov VeHaMeitiv.
>   However, for hearing good new which is only good for oneself, one
>   should make Shehecheyanu. (Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 59:1)

Note that after her treatment, she may be obliged to to make Birchat HaGomel (you can read about it [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birkat_HaGomel)). Please, ask a Rav.

Answer (score 2):

It's common to say *Boruch Hashem* which sometimes is translated as 'Bless is the Name' or 'Thank Hashem'.